# Grails: display linked table value in list.gsp instead of id

Tags: grails, grails-orm

*Let me preface this ask by indicating that this only applies to /list/ view and NOT other views.  This is NOT about drop-down menus*

I have two tables:

[Authors]
 - id
 - name

[Books]
 - id
 - title
 - author

In the **Books form** (create/edit) I can get the "author" field to display an author's name (from **Author** table instead of id) without an issue, however, when I view the /list/ view, it displays the author's id instead of the name (correctly, since this is what's stored in the DB).

I have not been able to find a method to convert "id" to "name" in the /list/ view elsewhere and I haven't used grails in almost a year (yay rust).  Thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: Please post the code that is not working.

Comment: There in lies the issue; this isn't a code break but instead producing functionality.  The response, as-is, is correct; I'm trying to alter it.

Comment: So it is that you just need to know how to modify the scaffolded view?  Are you generating the views or are you letting grails do it all dynamically?

Comment: I am letting grails generate everything and then coming in behind and making my changes.  I did this for the actual "book" form (added g:select pointing to "authors" table for the name/id pairing).  I was thinking of adding a "select..." def to the controller but think there's an easier way i'm not sure of (modifying fieldValue/bean call?).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Author {

    String name

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'name'
    }
}
```

If you're using static scaffolding, don't forget to regenerate the views for the Author and Book domain classes:

```
grails> generate-views com.yourPackage.Author
grails> generate-views com.yourPackage.Book
```

Comment: Perhaps the Author variable "name" is messing with the _id_ mapping argument _name_. Try changing the Author variable name to something like lastName, and then change the mapping to `id name: lastName`